# Can't find added jar files

Tags: java, build

I want to add the Gson jar files, this is what I've done to build.xml (the important part):

```
<property name="libs.dir" location="web/WEB-INF/lib" />
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${libs.dir}/gson">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${libs.dir}/tomcat">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
</javac>
```

The compiling goes great, but when I'm trying to start the application, it keeps saying that it can't find com.google.gson

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

I've tryed adding several other jars, and with every one of them it says no class found. However, the tomcat jar's are working. Is there perhaps something I'm missing?

Comment: Which libraries did you try to add?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant jar files. I've added the gson-2.2.2-javadoc.jar gson-2.2.2-sources.jar and gson-2.2.2.jar

Comment: libs.dir/gson ?? Perhaps you have copied jars at wrong place (assuming that by "start" you mean when running inside servlet container. Try placing all your jars under WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Hey thanks, ive added it in the /lib folder instead of /lib/gson and it worked! Thanks alot